# Manipulating Lua variables from C

Tags: lua, inline

I am trying to modify a Lua variable in C. I pass Lua userdata to a C function and the C function uses them and changes them. I want these values changed in Lua as well. Here's my code -

Lua -

```
 t = require 'coroutines'
 function foo()
      bar = 0
      foo1 = t.colorHistogram(bar)
      print(bar)
 end
```

C -

Here I do not know what to put. I read up how the two exchange data. Lua creates a stack that it pushes the arguments into and C accesses those args using the lua_Object. So

```
 int foo = lua_tonumber(L,1);
 foo = 5;
```

would initialize foo as 0 and set it to 5. However, the print statement in Lua still displays 0 as the value as it is not the memory where the variable "bar" in Lua is stored that is getting modified. I wanted to know if there is a way to modify the memory. I have also tried replacing the data on the stack with the modified value. That does not work either.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT**

I suppose I was not very clear in my original question. I tried sorry. Anyways, I'll try better -

What I basically want to do is pass a value to inline C, have C modify that value and be able to read it as modified in Lua. I do no care too much to modify that particular memory location or variable. As long as there is some way for me to read the value that C modified in Lua, I will take that.

```
 foo1, bar = t.colorHistogram(bar)
```

will not work because "t" is a lua function call and colorHistogram is an inline C function in that Lua function. If I pass bar to t.colorHistogram, I would need the Lua function "t" to be able to return bar which would mean I would need the Lua function "t" to read bar as modified. That is what I am not sure how to do. Thanks for your response btw. END EDIT

Comment: nil, booleans, numbers and strings are passed _by value_ in Lua, so as far as I can see you're effectively manipulating a copy on the stack.

Comment: Yes I know that. That is why I said it is not the memory where the variable is located that is being modified and that is why I tried modifying the value on the stack itself. It didn't work. Thanks for your response though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are not passed to functions; *values* are passed to functions. The number `0` is a value. `local bar = 0; t.colorHistogram(bar);` is functionally no different from `t.colorHistogram(0)`.

You cannot manipulate the content of a parameter variable from within a Lua function, because Lua functions are not passed variables. They're passed the *contents* of a variable.

Note that it doesn't matter whether it's a C-function or a Lua function; this is just how Lua parameter passing works. Parameters are inputs *only*; if you want to modify a "variable", then it either must be a global or an output that the caller stores into that variable:

```
bar = 0
foo1, bar = t.colorHistogram(bar)
```

Comment: A simple way to solve this, for me, would be to have a way for Lua to read from the stack. Is that possible? If Lua puts copies of the values I am passing to C on a "stack", it should be possible for Lua to read values off that stack as well.

Comment: @user1378064: Lua doesn't work that way. Lua does not read parameters back into variables. So unless you're talking about *changing* Lua (and I would strongly advise against it), that's not going to happen. The Lua language was designed to make it impossible to change the content of variables without the explicit use of an `=` sign. That's why there is no `++` or `--` operator in Lua. Screw with this at your peril.

Comment: Okay then is there a way of changing the variable WITH an = sign? The method is immaterial. I just want to pass an argument to C, have C modify it and then use that modified value in Lua. Is there no way that this can happen?

Comment: @user1378064: I explained how you use the equals sign: you set the variable equals to one of the return values of a function. If you're asking how to *return* values from a function, that's a different question. One you should look up in various Lua resources before asking here.